# how to pass a column with error: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, Timestamp('2021-03-02 05:45:42') was passed in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to create a line chart that displays the contents according to the specified keyword variables. I made it by taking the data in the csv file, which contains the columns: Keyword, Date, Tweet, Sentiment. When I use the if function to check whether the contents of the Keyword = field (the specified keyword variable), I get an error:

TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, Timestamp('2021-03-02 05:45:42') was passed.

I don't know which part I need to fix.
Here is my code:

```
query = "bali"
df = pd.read_csv('tes3.csv', header=None, 
                 names=["Keyword", "Date", "Tweet", "Sentimen"])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Keyword']==query:
        result = row.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='3s'), 'Sentimen']).count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here loop is not necesary, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then use `groupby`:

```
mask = df['Keyword']==query
result = df[mask].groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='3s'), 'Sentimen']).count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
```